# Express res.send not working

Tags: express, routes, xmlhttprequest

I have defined a variable so that I can store my endpoint in my express server.js file and I send it over a route called '/config' as shown below:

```
var webService,appConfig; 

webService = "some endpoint"; 
appConfig = {
        webServiceUrl: webService 
    };


app.get('/config', function(req, res) {
    res.send(appConfig);
});
```

However, when I set up my http request like so:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

    var
        isReady = (xhr.readyState === 4),
        isSuccess = (xhr.status === 200),
        config;

    if (isReady && isSuccess) {
        config = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        window._configUrl = config;
    }
}

xhr.open('GET', '/config', true);
xhr.send();
```

...it seems that the request is sending the index file instead of the variable I have defined. I have no idea why this would be happening. Any thoughts?

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: no it is actually sending the index file successfully